# Execute stored procedure per each row returned?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor, upsert

I have a stored procedure which gets two parameters from the user, namely `referenceNumber` and `destinationLocation` where `referenceNumber` is the unique identifier for the row and `destinationLocation` is where a requested item will be delivered. Please see table `tblStockMove` below:

```
deliveryID | ProductID | SourceLocation | DestinationLocation | Quantity | deliveryStart | deliveryEnd | ReferenceNumber | Status | Requestor | Receiver | ControlNumber | MoveType | ProductCode
13         | 1         |    WAREHOUSE   | Burger Queen        | 5        | 2016-11-14    | NULL        | CTRL_MULTI01    | PENDING| john.doe  | NULL     | CTRL_MULTI01  | MULTIPLE | 19000207
14         | 1         |    WAREHOUSE   | DcMo                | 4        | 2016-11-14    | NULL        | CTRL_MULTI01    | PENDING| john.doe  | NULL     | CTRL_MULTI01  | MULTIPLE | 19000207
15         | 1         |    WAREHOUSE   | Strapbucks          | 10       | 2016-11-14    | NULL        | CTRL_MULTI01    | PENDING| john.doe  | NULL     | CTRL_MULTI01  | MULTIPLE | 19000207
16         | 2         |    WAREHOUSE   | DcMo                | 6        | 2016-11-14    | NULL        | CTRL_MULTI01    | PENDING| john.doe  | NULL     | CTRL_MULTI01  | MULTIPLE | 19000209
```

What I want to achieve is to **bulk insert** all these records to their respective destination locations and update the quantity if that location had the same item before hand.

As such, I made this stored procedure which does a series of insert, update and drop:

```
CREATE procedure updateTBLStock
    @referenceNumber nvarchar(50),
    @destinationLocation nvarchar(50)
as begin
    --1) insert non existing items to a temporary table
      INSERT INTO tblTempStockList
      SELECT b.ProductID, a.ProductName, a.ProductCode, b.Quantity, a.UnitOfMeasure, 
      a.Provider, a.Category, a.ExpirationDate, b.DestinationLocation, b.ReferenceNumber
            FROM tblStockMove b
            inner join tblProducts_warehouse a on b.ProductCode = a.ProductCode 
            where b.ReferenceNumber = @referenceNumber
            and NOT EXISTS (Select a.ProductCode from tblProducts_establishments a
            where b.ProductCode = a.ProductCode 
            and a.Location = @destinationLocation
            and b.ReferenceNumber = @referenceNumber
            and b.MoveType = 'MULTIPLE')

    --2) update items' quantity if they already exist in the destination location
            UPDATE tblProducts_establishments 
            SET Quantity = a.Quantity + b.Quantity
            from tblProducts_establishments a 
            left join tblStockMove b
            on a.ProductCode = b.ProductCode 
            where b.ReferenceNumber = @referenceNumber 
            and b.MoveType = 'MULTIPLE' 
            and a.Location = @destinationLocation
            and EXISTS (Select a.ProductCode from tblProducts_establishments a 
            where b.ProductCode = a.ProductCode and a.Location = @destinationLocation
            and b.ReferenceNumber = @referenceNumber and b.MoveType = 'MULTIPLE')       

    --3) Insert the row from the temporary table to the main table

            INSERT INTO tblProducts_establishments (ProductID, ProductName, ProductCode, Quantity, UnitOfMeasure, Date, Provider, Category, ExpirationDate, Status, Location)
            SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductCode, Quantity, UnitOfMeasure, getdate(), Provider, Category, ExpirationDate, null, Location FROM tblTempStockList where ReferenceNumber = @referenceNumber and Location = @destinationLocation

    --4) Empty the temporary table
            DELETE FROM tblTempStockList where ReferenceNumber = @referenceNumber and Location = @destinationLocation
```

This query runs fine **IF** there is only one row (item) in one `referenceNumber` but won't insert properly if there are multiple entries.

So I tried to use a cursor but the it inserts duplicate ProductIDs per DestinationLocation.

```
declare @destinationLocation nvarchar(50)
declare @referenceNumber nvarchar(50)

declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
    select DestinationLocation, ReferenceNumber from tblStockMove where ControlNumber = 'CTRL_MULTI01'
open cur

fetch next from cur into @destinationLocation, @referenceNumber

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    execute updateTBLStock @referenceNumber, @destinationLocation

    fetch next from cur into @destinationLocation, @destinationLocation
END

close cur
deallocate cur
```

My question is, how can I successfully call the stored procedure using the cursor above? How do I pass two variables from the cursor that my stored procedure requires?

Comment: Your `CURSOR` is already doing it. Whats wrong with your current code ?

Comment: My SP is supposed to update the quantity of existing products in a specific establishment, say if `ProductID 1` exists in DcMo and tblStockMove has 5, then it will add them together. When using the cursor however, it inserts the same `ProductID` from tblStockMove, resulting in duplicate IDs in DcMo

Answer (score 0):

Pass Your parameters as table type variable by creating table as type 
like

```
 CREATE TYPE dbo.TBLStockType AS TABLE
 (
    referenceNumber nvarchar(50),
    destinationLocation nvarchar(50)
  )
```

GO

then user this type in your procedure like

```
CREATE procedure updateTBLStock
@referenceNumber TBLStockType READONLY,
@destinationLocation TBLStockType READONLY
as begin

    --your code here 
end
```

By using this you can pass multiple parameters at a time.
Pass your parameter as below

DECLARE @StockType AS TBLStockType

```
INSERT INTO @StockType
SELECT 'CTRL_MULTI01','DcMo'
union all 
select 'CTRL_MULTI01','DcMo'

--then execute proc

EXEC updateTBLStock @StockType
```